# ?ver= at the end of include - is there a technical effect?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

I wonder what exactly the version nameing does?

like jquery.js?ver=1.4.4

I mean if I use a cdn like this jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.4
but another side has jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2 in there, does this effect caching?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, by changing the `=1.4.4` to something else, it forces the file to not be cached by the browser when a user comes back to the page.  So if you upgraded to a new version of JQuery say 1.4.5, and you wanted to make sure that the client got the most current version of the file, you change the end of the url.  This makes the browser think that it's a brand new file and forces it to download the new version.

(Having the version at the end helps you easily identify which version of the file you have, but that is totally aside from what is being asked :) ).

Comment: Hm, ok. That means it's a potential error source (not really error). I mean the whole cdn caching thing is affected. So some people use it and some not and others maybee have the wrong version at the end. So best would be everybody would not use it on files they load from third party cdn's.

Comment: While this is correct, it is also possible that the *server may return a different resource* depending upon the version requested. If this is not the case (which is icky in itself) then I would simply move the version string into the resource name itself -- the "?ver=", for a stable version signature, is kind of a weak idea and may lead to subtle mismatches like MrGlasspoole has pointed out.

Comment: @pst yes, that is true too.  I should have added that.

Comment: @pst, what do you mean by version string into the resource name itself? The path and name is given by the cdn? Or do you mean what is allready there like "/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js".

Comment: Ok, found something http://nichol.as/how-google-is-wasting-your-bandwidth . So this whole caching thing is another half-baked caked. Tips here, tips there - the web is full of them. Put instand of saving you time, you have to research and prove everything *lol